# Recursive problems converting C code to MIPS Exponentiation

Tags: mips

I'm trying to do exponentiation with recursion, I'm struggling with the recursive part as it's getting stuck in an infinite loop. I'm just confused as to why it's getting stuck in the loop with power and even. Odd hasn't been started I was planning on reusing some of the code from even to get me started on odd.

C code

```
/* Prompt user for two non-negative integers. Raised the first to the
power of the second and print it. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
/* Is the parameter even? */
int is_even (int n);
/* Return a*b. */
int multiply (int a, int b);
/* Return a^b. */
int power (int base, int exponent);
int
main ()
{
  int base, exponent;
  printf ("Please enter non-negative base: ");
  scanf ("%d", &base);
  printf ("Please enter non-negative exponent: ");
  scanf ("%d", &exponent);
  if (base == 0 && exponent == 0)
    {
      printf ("Can't raise 0 to zero power.\n");
      exit (0);
    }
  int result = power (base, exponent);
  printf ("%d^%d=%d\n", base, exponent, result);
}

/* Determine if a non-negative number is even by inspecting
the least-significant bit. A leaf procedure. */
int
is_even (int n)
{
  if ((n & 0x1) == 0)
    {
      return TRUE;
    }
  return FALSE;

}

/* Multiply the parameters together by repeated addition. A leaf
procedure. */
int
multiply (int a, int b)
{
  int result = 0;
  while (a > 0)
    {
      result += b;
      a--;
    }
  return result;
}

/* Calculate b raised to the power of a recursively. */
int
power (int b, int e)
{
  int even_exponent, temp, result;
/* Base case of the recursion: exponent is 0. */
  if (e == 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
/* There are two recursive cases. First, determine whether
the exponent is even or odd. */
  even_exponent = is_even (e);
  if (even_exponent)
    {
/* Even case. */
      temp = power (b, e / 2);
      result = multiply (temp, temp);
    }
  else
    {
/* Odd case. */
      temp = power (b, (e - 1) / 2);
      result = multiply (b, temp);
      result = multiply (result, temp);
    }
  return result;
}
```

MIPS code

```
power:
#If exponent $s1 is equal to zero returns 1 as result
beq $s1,$zero,expoZero
addi $t0,$t0,1
jal checkEven

#if base is even go to even
beq $s2,$zero,even
beq $s2,$t1,odd
#if base is odd go to odd

addi $sp, $sp, 4
lw $ra, 0($sp)
checkEven:

#Check if exponent is even or odd
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $s1, 0($sp)
andi $s2,$s1,0x1

lw $s1, 0($sp)
lw $ra, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp 8
jr $ra



expoZero:
#returns 1
li $s3, 1

jr $ra


even:
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra,0($sp)

#if the base is even it performs a^(b/2)*a^(b/2)

srl $s1,$s1,1       #$s1/2

jal power
move $s4,$v0

move $a0,$s4
move $a1,$s4
jal multiply
#returns result
addi $s3, $s3, 1

addi $sp, $sp, 4
lw $ra,0($sp)
jr $ra

odd:
#if the base is odd it performs a*a^((b-1)/2)*a^((b-1)/2)

#returns result
addi $s3, $s3, 1

jr $ra


multiply:
addi $sp, $sp -24
sw $ra, 20($sp)
sw $s0, 16($sp)
sw $s1, 12($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)
sw $s3, 4($sp)
sw $s4, 0($sp)

#set result equal to zero
move $s3,$zero

#test for a > 0
slt $t2,$a0,$zero   #a < 0

loop:
#while (a<0)
beq $t2,$zero,exit
add $s3,$s3,$a1     #result += b
addi $a0,$a0,-1     #a--

j loop


exit:
lw $s4, 0($sp)
lw $s3, 4($sp)
lw $s2, 8($sp)
lw $s1, 12($sp)
lw $s0, 16($sp)
lw $ra, 20($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 24
j power
```

Comment: You don't need to recursion at all :)

Comment: I'm supposed to do it recursively. The C code should be translated into MIPS. @user1095108

Comment: How can the base case be only `e==0` when dividing e by 2 will never result in zero?  Surely the base case should be `e==0` returning 1 followed by `e==1`  returning b?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah only if we are very pedantic and want to avoid UB.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
int pow(int const x, unsigned const e)
{
  int const y(e % 2 ? x : 1);
  //int const y(((x ^ 1) & -(e % 2)) ^ 1);

  return !e ? 1 : 1 == e ? x : pow(x * x, e / 2) * y;
}
```

Shouldn't be too hard to convert to MIPS.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WeWPnfoq4) made this:

```
pow(int, unsigned int):
        b       $L4
        li      $2,1                        # 0x1

$L9:
        beq     $5,$0,$L6
        nop

        beq     $5,$3,$L3
        li      $6,1                        # 0x1

$L10:
        mult    $2,$6
        srl     $5,$5,1
        mflo    $2
        nop
        nop
        mult    $4,$4
        mflo    $4
$L4:
        andi    $3,$5,0x1
        beq     $3,$0,$L9
        li      $3,1                        # 0x1

        bne     $5,$3,$L10
        move    $6,$4

$L3:
        mult    $4,$2
        mflo    $2
        j       $31
        nop

$L6:
        li      $4,1                        # 0x1
        mult    $4,$2
        mflo    $2
        j       $31
        nop
```

See? Recursion was optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help, I'm supposed to translate the C code mentioned above.

Comment: @muncheeboy2 the C code you provided is written to confuse you. Evil teacher.